# SMTP: SSL_connect fails but no errors

Tags: c, email, smtp, openssl

I'm having trouble with the openssl library. I'm calling the following function after sending `EHLO` and `STARTTLS`:

```
SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
SSL *ssl = NULL;

    void CreateTLSSession(int sockfd)
    {
        printf("///////////////creating TLS Session/////////////////////\n");
        SSL_library_init();
        SSL_load_error_strings();
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
        if (ctx == NULL)
        {
            printf("failed to initialize context\n");
            return;
        }
        SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        if (!SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd))
        {
            printf("failed to bind to socket fd\n");
            return;
        }
        if (SSL_connect(ssl) < 1)
        {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
            fflush(stdout);
            printf("SSL_connect failed\n");
            return;
        }
    }
```

However, `SSL_connect` fails but does not print any errors!

Here's the output of my code: (including the replies of the server)

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP x3sm39000551eep.17 - gsmtp 




//////////////////////////EHLO////////////////////////// 
250-mx.google.com at your service, [80.149.109.201] 
250-SIZE 35882577 
250-8BITMIME 
250-STARTTLS 
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
250 CHUNKING 




//////////////////////////STARTTLS////////////////////////// 
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 




///////////////creating TLS Session///////////////////// 
SSL_connect failed
```

so `ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout)` is not doing anything!

Any idea why this is happening?

BTW, I'm trying to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587

Comment: If you are trying to connect with TLS and Compression, then you need to disable compression. Its a Google quirk - SNI and Comp are apparently mutually exclusive. Add `SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION` to your socket options.

Comment: @noloader I added SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx,SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION) but the problem remains.

Comment: Well, I would try two additional items. First, I would load Google's CA with `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`. You can get Google's CA at [Google Internet Authority G2](http://pki.google.com/). Second, I would set the server name with `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name`. Since SNI is TLS, disable SSLv3 with `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3`. After that, I'm not sure what to do because I don't know the MSA message flows.

Comment: The OpenSSL docs on [`SSL_connect(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_connect.html) state to call `SSL_get_error(ssl, ret)` to get the error code, btw. You can find the docs at [`SSL_get_error(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_error.html).

Comment: @noloader I found a working code at https://github.com/muquit/mailsend/blob/master/smtp.c  . The code does exactly the same thing I'm doing. I don't know what I am missing. I'll give `SSL_get_error`a try.

Comment: Well, if its doing exactly the same thing, then it should not work either ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to finally solve the problem. the underlying socket was non-blocking, so SSL_connect does not connect instantly. Using `select` solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a load of private key file or certificate file. use SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file and SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file.

Comment: I believe he would only need that with a server, not a client. Unless he's using client certs, which I don't think apply here.